# Postman REST Client OAuth 2.0 - Extra Payload for Quizlet API

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman

I'm trying to use the Postman REST Client to test the [Quizlet API](https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/authorization-code-flow). Postman has a feature to do OAuth 2.0 for you. However, the Quizlet API requires a `state` parameter:

> A random string generated by you. You send us this, and we'll send it back to you, and you verify that we send back the same thing you sent. You **must** send and verify this value in order to prevent CSRF attacks.

The default Postman helper does not have the ability to send more in the POST (as far as I know). Is there a known way to send the extra payload, or get around this (whether in Postman or the Quizlet API?)

Thanks in advance!

**Steps:**

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

[image: Step 5]

[image: Step 6]